# Delay JS until ng-view elements have been loaded into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to do form validation, but once I stick my form into an ng-view and use ngroute, the DOM element gets delayed a bit and my script is unable to find the element when it runs.

I don't want to do something hacky like `setInterval`

I have something like this:

```
validateform.ready = function() {

$valForm   = $('.ui.basic.login-register.segment .ui.form.segment');
  $.fn.form.settings.defaults = {
    firstName: {
      identifier  : 'first_name',
      rules: [
        {
          type   : 'empty',
          prompt : 'Please enter your first name'
        }
      ]
    },
  ... // More validation code
  $valForm
    .form({}, {
      inline : true,
      on: 'blur'
    });

  $('.ui.dropdown')
      .dropdown();

  $('.ui.accordion')
      .accordion();
};
```

I then call `$(document).ready(validateform.ready);`, but apparently that's too early when `ng-view` is in play.

My understanding is because the `ready` event occurs, then Angular does its routing and injects the `ng-view` then.

How could I make sure this code is loaded after the element is there?

Comment: I think the real solution is to use Angular form validation. Why are you using external jQuery and whatnot for things that Angular can do, built in?

Comment: I was given the client-side validation code by the original developer. I have no issue with figuring out and using Angular validation, but my guess is other people have solved this problem before.

Comment: @Ian And also because I will probably need to do something other than validation and run into a similar problem

Comment: For what it's worth, here's an example of simple form validation (and CSS styling): http://jsfiddle.net/75Rcb/ - there's **a lot** more you can do with this